# How can I install a custom version of Apache Spark on Cloud Dataproc

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

For one reason or another, I want to install a version of [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org) different from the one available on [Google Cloud Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc). How can I install a custom version of Spark but also maintain compatibility with the Cloud Dataproc tooling?

Answer (score 7):

In general, you should be able to install a custom version of Spark on Dataproc and maintain compatibility with the Cloud Dataproc tooling (Cloud Dataproc jobs, mainly.)

To do this, you should:

1. Install spark in `/usr/local/lib/spark` or `/opt/spark` instead of the user home directory
2. Don't modify the user `.bashrc`
3. Uninstall the Cloud Dataproc-provided version of spark using `apt-get remove`
4. Symlink `/usr/local/bin/spark-submit` to the provided binary (this is needed for the Cloud Dataproc jobs API to work with the new Spark install)
5. Re-use the `/etc/spark/conf` provided by Cloud Dataproc

Comment: would this happen during the custom-image build script or the initiation script?

Comment: did it in init script

Comment: @pavbagel do you mind sharing your init script somewhere? (pastebin or github gist)

Comment: Don't have it anymore, but found that doing it in the init script was the easiest way.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the steps above I had to set SPARK_HOME via `/etc/profile.d/`

`echo export SPARK_HOME=/opt/my/new/spark/ > /etc/profile.d/set_spark_home.sh`

Comment: did you do this on the custom-image build script or the initiation script?

Comment: did it in init script

Comment: yep, init script